# If $F : K → M$ is a group-homomorphism such that $\text{Range}(F )$ is not empty, $K$ is simple and $M$ a finite group. How to show that $|M| ≥ |K|$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If  $F : K → M$ be a group-homomorphism such that $\text{Range}(F)$ is not empty. If  $K$ is simple and $M$ is a finite group. How to show that $|M| ≥ |K|$.

What I know is:
$ |k|=|\text{Ker}(f)|\times|\text{Range}(f)|$ but I still do not know how to show the inequality.

Comment: What are $H$ and $D$?

Comment: I mean k and M it is just a typo

Answer (score 1):

I believe you wat to say that the image is not trivial since it is never empty since its contains always the neutral element. The kernel of $F$ is a normal subgroup since the image is not trivial and $K$ is simple, it is the trivial subgroup so $F$ is injective.

Comment: if F is injective,how this will help me to show |M| ≥ |K|